# Call object's method from another method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some module file:

```
const dbModule = module.exports = {
  setBase: (apiKey, base) => new Airtable({ apiKey }).base(base),
  base: dbModule.setBase('', '')
}
```

But I get an error message during compile: `variable 'dbModule' used before its declaration`.

So how can I define `base` method to call `setBase` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than declare the variable you are exporting as one step, you could separate it out into multiple steps:

```
const dbModule = {
  setBase: (apiKey, base) => ....
};

dbModule.base = dbModule.setBase('', '');

module.exports = dbModule;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have defined dbModule elsewhere in your code.

```
class dbModule {

  setBase() {
  ....
  }
  base() {
    setBase();
  }
};
module.exports = new dbModule();
```

This class based programming makes sure that each of your functions belong to the class object and can access one another.